# Как обработать несколько значений val?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

К примеру есть код:

```js
$("#select").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "value1") {
    $("#input").show();
  } else {
    $("#input").hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="select">
    <option value="value1">Value1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value3</option>
    <div id="input" style="display: none;">Ввод</div>
 </select>
</form>
```

Как обработать несколько значений if($(this).val() == "value1"){ например value1 и value2 ?

Comment: читаю вопрос и не понял...

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо проверить одно значение на совпадение нескольким другим, то можно использовать `$.inArray()` в JQuery [Описание](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), предварительно скомпоновав проверяемые значения в массив. Если необходимо менять код в зависимости от того, какое значение, то это стандартный оператор `switch`

Answer (score 0):

Если не менять структуру используйте [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

```html
switch(expression) {
    case 'value1':
        code block
        break;
    case 'value2':
        code block
        break;
    default:
        code block
}
```